# What's the free product of $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z *\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z $?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, free-product

What's the free product of $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z *\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z $?

Let $G=H=\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z *\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z =\langle g\in\{0,1,2\}\mid 3g\equiv0\pmod 3\rangle$

Then I have that the free product of groups $J$ is:

$J=G*H=\langle g,h\mid 3g\equiv3h\equiv0\pmod 3\rangle$

I'm seeing this as the set of ordered pairs $\{g,h\}$ which has $9$ elements, which I know is wrong but I don't understand why.

What do the elements of $J$ look like?

Comment: The set of ordered pairs is the direct product, not the free product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not the set of ordered pairs. Its more natural in this setting to write our group operation multiplicatively, so $g^3=1$ etc., and then we can view this group $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ as the set of all words of the form:
$$
g^{\alpha_1}h^{\beta_1}\cdots g^{\alpha_n}h^{\beta_n}
$$
where $\alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n, \beta_1, \ldots, \beta_{n-1}\in\{1, 2\}$ and $\alpha_1, \beta_n\in\{0, 1, 2\}$ (this last condition just allows for the first and end letters of the word to change).

Multiplication is concatenation-then-reduction, for example multiplying $hgh^2$ and $hg^2h$ gives:
$$
\begin{align*}
hgh^2\cdot hg^2h&=hgh^3g^2h\\
&=hg1g^2h\\
&=hg^3g\\
&=h1g\\
&=h^2.
\end{align*}
$$
Using this view, its clear that this group is infinite. (Note that people often use $\epsilon$ for the identity element in this setting, where $\epsilon$ denotes the empty word, rather than $1$.)

Being slightly more formal, what is going on here is that the group is equivalence classes of words over the symbols $g$ and $h$, where $U$ and $V$ are equivalent if one can be obtained from the other by adding and removing words of the form $g^3$ and $h^3$. All I've done above is pick a single representative from each equivalence class. This is the kind of view taken in, for example, the book *Combinatorial group theory* by Magnus, Karrass and Solitar, or the book *Combinatorial group theory* by Lyndon and Schupp*.

For an added geometric twist, consider the infinite tree where each vertex has valency $3$ (the "trivalent tree"). Colour the vertices blue and red such that no adjacent vertices have the same colour. Then the free product $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ acts by rotations on this tree (you can think of the "left" group as the "blue" group and the "right" group as the "red" group). For more details, see the very readable book "Groups, graphs and trees" by John Meier.

*Why yes, these books do have the same name.

Comment: Thanks. I was imagining was the free *abelian* group. I know what a free group looks like, so I see clearly the key difference is that $g,h$ do not commute in a non-abelian free group.  But I just can't reconcile this with the question of whether these elements $hhg$ etc, can be written using $0,1,2$ instead of $h,g$, and if so, what that would look like.  I mean $fffggg\equiv ffgggf\equiv0$ when we use $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$.  I think if I could see the group operation on $0,1,2$ looked like. The best sense I can make of what you describe is it looks like a map through sequences of ordered pairs.

Comment: Well, you need to differentiate the left group and the right group. So you could use $\{1_g, 2_g\}$ and $\{1_h, 2_h\}$ (the identity $0$ is common to both groups) and then words look like $1_g2_h1_g1_h2_g$. However, this is basically the same as $\{g^1, g^2\}$ and $\{h^1, h^2\}$, I've just messed around with the placing of the $2$ and the $h$, etc.... Also, the $2_g$ notation puts an emphasis on the exponent $2$ rather than the group $g$, and in practice I find that the actual group the element belong to is more important than the specific group element in that position. So stick with $g^2$.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?